# How do I update tableview cell when It had changed

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, parse-server

When I scroll up&down then tableview cell has set overtimes so It affect lagging.

I want to update only when the data is updated.

**Post.swift (It is model)**

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class Post: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    @NSManaged var postBy: PFUser?

    @NSManaged var postUser: String?
    @NSManaged var postUserImg: PFFile?



    @NSManaged var postText: String?
    @NSManaged var postImg: PFFile?
    @NSManaged var sell: NSNumber?

    @NSManaged var commentPointer: PFObject?
    @NSManaged var commentBy: String?
    @NSManaged var comment: String?

    @NSManaged var liked: NSArray?
    @NSManaged var likeCount: NSNumber?

    @NSManaged var mention: NSArray?
    @NSManaged var hashtag: NSArray?


    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Post"
    }



    override class func query() -> PFQuery<PFObject>? {

        let query = PFQuery(className: Post.parseClassName())


        return query
    }

}

extension Post: FeedCellSupport {


    var username:String?{


        return postUser
    }

    var userImg:PFFile?{



        return postUserImg
    }

    var commentText:String?{

        guard let commentTxt = comment else {
            return ""
        }


        return commentTxt


    }
```

**TableView.swift**

```
protocol FeedCellSupport {
    var postDate: String? { get }
    var postId: String? { get }
    var postObj: PFObject? { get }
    var img: PFFile? { get }
    var username:String?{ get }
    var userImg:PFFile?{ get }

    var commentText:String?{ get }
    var commentFrom:String?{ get }

    var postText: String? { get }
    var likes: Int? { get }
    var isLiked: Bool? { get }
    var isSell: Bool? { get }

    var hashtags: NSArray? { get }
    var mentions: NSArray? { get }

}


func fetchObjects() {

        let postQuery = Post.query()?
                        .whereKeyExists("objectId")
                        .includeKeys(["postBy", "commentPointer", "commentPointer.commentBy", "commentBy"])
                        .order(byDescending: "createdAt")
                        as! PFQuery<Post>

        postQuery.limit = self.page
        postQuery.cachePolicy = .networkElseCache

        postQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (object:[Post]?, error:Error?) in

            if error == nil {

                self.results = object!

            }else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        }


    }


 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShopDetailCell", for: indexPath) as! ShopDetailCell

        if let object = results[indexPath.row] as? FeedCellSupport{




            cell.postID = object.postObj!
            cell.userNameLabel.text = object.username!
            cell.userNameLabel.sizeToFit()

            cell.descriptionLabel.text = object.postText!
            cell.descriptionLabel.sizeToFit()

            cell.commentByLabel.text = object.commentFrom!
            cell.commentByLabel.sizeToFit()

            cell.commentLabel.text = object.commentText!
            cell.commentLabel.sizeToFit()
 cell.delegate = self

        }
        return cell
    }
```

How can I ensure that data is updated only when it changes?

Comment: That is not possible, well, not intended. The tableView reuses it's cells. If you scroll, the cell that last leaft the screen is used again for the one that is showing next. This is good as it avoids steady initialization of cells. If it's laggy, it's your fault.

Comment: Try `DispatchGroup.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }` instead of `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Hi Sungwookbaek, have you considered to add a didSet property observer to the properties that fill your cells? You can call reloadData() from the property observer. It is a bit cumbersome, but it should work.

Comment: @shallowThought Thanks for the reply. I had tried DispatchGroup.main.async but still laggy. I'm trying to initialize cell. Thanks

Comment: @MacUserT Thanks I did not tried yet. I will try didSet. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

What are your App functionalities? Your problem is associated with the way suitable to accomplish your task, that is: to update app contents.

So it is about business logic: when should the information be updated?

The solution to your problem is using **user toggled events** to refresh the contents or other possible solutions such as **Application Delegate**.

Except for these answers, the contents **cannot** update tableview  **automatically**  as your expectation.

**Update**

I considered this line of code is lagging:

```
if let object = results[indexPath.row] as? FeedCellSupport{
    //other code
}
```

Because code inside these braces is dealing with data setting. You could try to mock up local data instead of this `results` array to say whether this is the problem.

Comment: I'm using the parse-server. So when data has been changed or created then called event handler to update my tableview's cell. It is no problem. My problem is when I scroll up and down then this function "override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {" called and set data every time. So I feel laggy.

Comment: @sungwookbaek Maybe something goes wrong with this line `code `if let object = results[indexPath.row] as? FeedCellSupport `code`

Comment: @sungwookbaek  I updated my answer according to your explain. Sorry for bad formatting of former comment, because I'm new to comment system.  You could delete it if you want to.